# PubSub Push Subscription have spikes in unacked message count

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm running a Push subscription to an endpoint handled by Google load balancer, which points to a Kubernetes ingress, and a K8 NodePort Service. Behind the service there are 6 pods (1 CPU, 4 GB RAM each) servicing the push traffic so I'm pretty confident that processes to handle the push traffic is not a problem.

I get these spikes in "unacked message count" every hour and it baffles me how it happened.

Is it possible that pubsub is not pushing fast enough? If yes, how do I "configure" pubsub to push faster with more throughput?

**More stats:**

- Push latency of around 50-150ms
- Number of push requests: Avg of 5 per second
- Outstanding push messages always < 1
- Min backoff: 1s
- Max backoff: 8s
- Ack deadline: 15s

[image]

Comment: Your issue is not due to Cloud Pub/Sub not pushing fast enough, but due to the messages not getting acknowledged.

Comment: @KrishanuSengupta can you resend the link please ;)

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further. If you have a [support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). As you will have to share your project ID, please use  this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for more details .